# How to paste multiple Excel charts into a PowerPoint presentation?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to paste charts from Excel being into PowerPoint in specific locations.

I get an error when pasting a second slide

> Invalid request. To select a shape its view must be active

I have seen to use `ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide oSlide.SlideIndex` and I know what I'm trying to do. I just do not know how to implement this.

```
Sub ChartToPresentation()
    ' Uses Early Binding to the PowerPoint Object Model
    ' Set a VBE reference to Microsoft PowerPoint Object Library
    Dim PPApp  As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim nPlcHolder As Long

    ' Reference existing instance of PowerPoint
    Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
    ' Reference active presentation
    Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation
    PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide

    'Copy "Chart 1" on "Sheet1" to Slide # 1
    ' Copy "Chart 1" on "Sheet1" as a picture and want to paste to placeholder 
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").CopyPicture
    ' Paste chart  to Slide # 1
    With PPPres
        nPlcHolder = 2 '<~~ The place holder where you have to paste
        .Slides(1).Shapes.Placeholders(nPlcHolder).Select msoTrue
        .Windows(1).View.PasteSpecial (ppPasteMetafilePicture)
    End With

    'Copy "Chart 5" on "Sheet1" to Slide # 2
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 5").CopyPicture
    ' Paste chart  to Slide # 2
    With PPPres
        nPlcHolder = 2 '<~~ The place holder where you have to paste
        .Slides(2).Shapes.Placeholders(nPlcHolder).Select msoTrue
        .Windows(1).View.PasteSpecial (ppPasteMetafilePicture)
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just select the slides it works:

```
With PPPres
     nPlcHolder = 2 '<~~ The place holder where you have to paste
    '.Slides(1).Shapes.Placeholders(nPlcHolder).Select msoTrue
    .Slides(1).Select
    .Windows(1).View.PasteSpecial (ppPasteMetafilePicture)
End With

[...]

With PPPres
     nPlcHolder = 2 '<~~ The place holder where you have to paste
    '.Slides(2).Shapes.Placeholders(nPlcHolder).Select msoTrue
    .Slides(2).Select
    .Windows(1).View.PasteSpecial (ppPasteMetafilePicture)
End With
```

After copying the charts to your PowerPoint slides you may want to move and zoom them by changing their picture properties.

Comment: easy fix. Thank you so much !